# Can't check NSLocaleLanguageCode value by IF condition!

Tags: objective-c, nslocale

I'm displaying **localLanguage** and got a value of *en* which is correct 100% based on my device selected language.

Then I checked **localLanguage** value to do some alignments, but the problem is not falling in the *en* condition! Its always falling in *ELSE* condition! Am I checking the value incorrectly?

```
NSString *localLanguage = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleLanguageCode];
NSLog(@"%@",localLanguage);

if (localLanguage == @"en") {
  NSLog(@"EN");
} else if (localLanguage == @"ar") {
  NSLog(@"AR");
} else {
  NSLog(@"XX");
}
```

Please help :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `isEqualToString:` for string comparisons.

```
if ( [localLanguage isEqualToString:@"en"] ) {
    ....
```